# Obico Tunneling Nginx Configuration

Tags: networking, arch-linux, nginx, tunnel, reverse-proxy

ive got some problems with setting up obico tunneling as the documentation doesnt tell you how you need to configure nginx.

So you have following ports wich are for tunneling: 15853, 15854, 15855, 15856, 15857 und 15858

Ive you open a new tunnel to you octoprint you get redirected to https://yourobico.local/tunnels/1/ and with network analysis i noticed a request to https://yourobico.local/octoprint/1/ wich shows a forbidden icon on status. If i double click that it redirects me to http://yourobico.local:15856/login/?redirect=%2F%3F&permissions=STATUS%2CSETTINGS_READ and shows the site it should tunnel to.

The documentation only tells me this: "All the ports in the range above needs to be forwarded by your reverse proxy. The details depend on the reverse proxy of your choice and is beyond the scope of this guide."

I already tried around but to be honest, in my years with nginx i didnt needed this kind of configuration and i am really stuck as the discord also cant help me with that.

This is my current configuration which of course doesnt work :(

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;

server_name yourobico.local;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/obico.error.log;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourobico.local/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourobico.local/privkey.pem;

client_max_body_size 250m;

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
ssl_early_data on;




location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3334;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}

   location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3334/ws/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   }

   location /octoprint/1/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15856;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        allow all;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

   }

location /octoprint/2/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15854;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}

location /octoprint/3/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15855;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}

location /octoprint/4/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15856;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}

location /octoprint/5/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15857;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}

location /octoprint/6/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15858;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
}
```

Thank you for any help!